# How work the RenderMode.InteractiveAuto Blazor Web APP .NET 8

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I'm trying to understand the render mode "RenderMode.InteractiveAuto".
Everything works until I visit a page with the render mode "RenderMode.InteractiveServer", after that all my pages stay in render mode server.

I added this code : `OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "WASM":"SERVEUR"` for display in which mode my page is render.

For example with the sample project "Blazor Web App", I duplicate the counter but I set the render mode to : @rendermode InteractiveServer
[My Visual Studio files explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg7LP.png)

There is the code of Counter.razor :

```
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<p>@(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "WASM" : "SRV")</p>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

There is the code of CounterServeur.razor :

```
@page "/counterSRV"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<p>@(OperatingSystem.IsBrowser() ? "WASM" : "SRV")</p>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

When I launch the application and then I go to Counter.razor (with NavMenu), my page is in WASM mode (it's ok) :
[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSEIN.png)

After that I go to CounterServeur.razor (with NavMenu), my page is in SERVER mode (it's ok) :
[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXxRm.png)

And then when I go back to Counter.razor (with NavMenu), my page is in SERVER mode and not in WASM mode :
[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J6iI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog (https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html) that answer to my question so I share it. It seems that the the transition between Server mode and Auto mode is normal.

> 1. SSSR - classic Static Server Side Rendering.
> 2. ASSR - Active Server Side Rendering. Blazor Server.
> 3. CSR - Client Side Rendering. Blazor WASM/Web Assembly.
>
> **InteractiveAuto Pages don't always render in the same mode**
>
> Go to Home and then to Counter. Counter renders in CSR mode with the
> CSR service instance.
>
> Now go to ASSR and then back to Counter. It's now rendered in ASSR
> mode, and uses the Blazor Hub service instance.
>
> Consider saving the state of the counter in a service. You get
> different states depending on the render mode.

Accord to https://shauncurtis.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment.  It's my conclusion based on quite a lot of experimentation I've done.  It's relatively new ground for all of us, so there may be things I've missed [and others find].

Comment: I got the same feeling with my first experimentations, let's see how that evolve !